# Catch application exe config file error

Tags: c#, corrupt, exe.config

I have recently build a application that run on few client machines. Application run as window start up. In this application i am modifying some `key` parameters of application run time by accessing it using the following method. 
`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)`

Occasionally (Don't know why ??) , config file gets corrupted and application crashes on system reboot with following message

`application failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect`

I want to catch this exception. I have tried putting `try-catch` block in `main()` method of application, but still exception not handled and those weird message box coming.

How can i handle `corrupted config file` ?

Comment: if it's windows service there should be OnStart() method.

Comment: What does a corrupted config file look like?

Comment: It actually not a window service, but start on window start up .

Comment: @rene empty file, Notepad only shows white spaces

Comment: You should fix that, because I doubt if much managed code is executed when the config file is mangled.

Comment: Why do you use the `ConfigurationManager` at all? .NET itself will load the application's configuration file. Why don't you leave it alone?

Comment: @rene What i should fix ? You mean to say, i should not modify key param of file run time !!!

Comment: Yes, you also shouldn't to that. If you want to modify settings, use user settings and do things properly.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar i am updating one of key param runtime. i am using `ConfigurationManager` to access the config file runtime

Comment: @RajeevKumar Don't! Whatever reason you think you may have. Don't.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register a global exception handler to you appDomain at program startup, e.g. in your app.xaml:

```
var currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.UnhandledException += GlobalUnhandledExceptionHandler;
```

In the GlobalUnhandledExceptionHandler Event Handler you can log the error or show a message to the user that the configuration file is broken.

This will not prevent your application from shutting down but at least you know more than "side-by-side configuration is broken".